# nodeJS cannot receive request from React API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, amazon-s3

I got a front-end running React. This my code to call the API

```
componentDidMount(){
      const jso = JSON.stringify({
        username: 'admin@etsmtl.ca',
        password: 'admin'
      })
      fetch("https://desolate-escarpment-15258.herokuapp.com/authentication", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: jso,
      }).then(res => res.json()).then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          answer: result.answer
        })

      }, (error) => {
        this.setState({isLoaded: true, error});

      })
  }
```

Now this is the code from nodeJS server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

//setting port
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

//helps node to pasre JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Enabeling all Access-Control-Allow-Origin
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send({answer: "hello world!"});
})

app.post('/authentication', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send({answer: req.body});
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("app running");
})
```

The problem : nodeJS is unable to handle the request from React.

I now that the connection between both servers works because I can receive an answer when I do `res.send("hello Wolrd");` in nodeJS

FYI, nodeJS is hosted by heroku and reactJS by AWS S3. But we tried locally and it neither worked

Comment: Have you tried doing `res.send(200, {answer: req.body})` ?

Comment: Is it throwing an error message or something? Or is there no output at all? What's happening exactly?

Comment: Also you are doing `(error) => {
        this.setState({isLoaded: true, error});

      })`, is anything getting set in state for `error`?

Comment: when I do the following command : `curl --request POST --data "username=admin" https://desolate-escarpment-15258.herokuapp.com/authentication` I receive this : `{"answer":{}}`

Comment: That's a good sign. At least there is an answer attribute in the respnse. What is returned when you do `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username":"admin@etsmtl.ca","password":"admin"}' \
  https://desolate-escarpment-15258.herokuapp.com/authentication`?

Comment: If you want, you can try it by your self as it is hosted in Heroku. But it returns `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Bad Request</pre>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do it!! Basically, we need to prevent the use of url...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mysql = require("mysql");

//setting port
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

//helps node to pasre JSON
/*LINE BELOW HAS BEEN ADDED TO PREVENT USE OF URL*/
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//etc...
```

Answer (score -1):

In componentDidMount() `body` is set to `jso`. Change to `body: json`
Perharps it might work.

Set `app.use(cors())` like this `app.use(cors( {origin: '*' }))`;

I also had a siimilar issue where when I was in build mode I am able to access my database on the backend but when I uploaded to a subdomain(Netlify) it seized to work.

It didn't work for me in Netlify but you should try to see i this might work in heroku.

Comment: `jso` is defined above `const jso = JSON.stringify({
        username: 'admin@etsmtl.ca',
        password: 'admin'
      })`